# How Can I Use Join In The Leftjoin With Laravel？

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a question on leftjoin & join in laravel
I want to rewrite following sample to laravel, how can I do this ?

```
LEFT JOIN(advertsolution_f SF 
          JOIN function_d FD ON SF.fd_id = FD.fd_id 
          JOIN function_m FM ON FD.fm_id = FM.fm_id) 
ON SM.ads_id = SF.ads_id
```

i try to rewrite it like this,but i think it is not a good idea.

```
->leftJoin($SF,$SM.'.ads_id',$SF.'.ads_id')
->leftjoin($FD,$SF.'.fd_id',$FD.'.fd_id')
->leftjoin($FM,$FD.'.fm_id',$FM.'.fm_id')
```

because i have no idea how to join table to $SF privately.

Comment: what error you are facing, can you post the error

Comment: When my conditions are not accurate enough,CMD will collapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map like this,

```
->leftJoin($SF,$SM.'.ads_id','=',$SF.'.ads_id')
->leftjoin($FD,$SF.'.fd_id','=',$FD.'.fd_id')
->leftjoin($FM,$FD.'.fm_id','=',$FM.'.fm_id')
```

You are missing = sign in query.

**EDIT**

EXAMPLE YOU GIVEN, I am writing query on behalf of it, you just need to map with your original fields and tables,

```
DB::table('a')
->leftJoin("b","b.a_id","=","a.id")
->leftJoin("c","c.b_id","=","b.id")
->leftJoin("d","d.bd_id","=","b.bdid")
->get();
```

Map this query, as per your requirement,
it should work.

Comment: thx,but it's work without that , I just feel strange on useing three leftjoin

Comment: Thats database logic right ? where to use inner & left, that you need to decide

Comment: for exlample :
  I have 4 table a b c d , table a is my mine table , table b leftjoin table a
  and then table c and table d join table b.

Comment: or tell me, shall I map your core query which you mentioned in question, means I will take all table and field names as static unlike you had taken them in variable ?

Comment: Now what else your expectations ?

Comment: this means ? what would be the problem, are you trying to say, so many left join is it right/ wrong ?

Comment: i am worry about that too many leftjoin will let server collapse

Comment: For the same, I will suggest you to study, dependancy/relations in between tables you are using, left you use when the table coupling wouldn't be that strong, inner is for mandatory matching, check once.

Comment: go on mate. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For making such complex query you can use `RAW EXPRESSIONS` like:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
->where('status', '<>', 1)
->get();
```

**Raw Expressions**

Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points! To create a raw expression.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)